# d3.js: axisBottom is appearing at the top instead

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, visualization, axis-labels

I'm trying to add an X-axis to the bottom of my D3 (v5) generated graph, as below. However, the X-axis appears at the top, even though I am calling `axisBottom()`. Is there a mistake that I'm making somewhere?

```
results = {
  x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  y: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
  y1: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
}

const W = 1000,
      H = 620,
      margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50,
      };

const width = W - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = H - margin.top - margin.bottom;

let scaleX = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([results.x[0], results.x[results.x.length-1]]) // x is produced by numpy.linspace
  .range([0, width]);

let ymax = Object.keys(results)
  .filter(k => k !== 'x')
  .map(k => d3.max(results[k].y))
  .reduce((x, y) => Math.max(x, y), -Infinity);

let scaleY = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, ymax])
  .range([height, 0]);

let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(scaleX);

let svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .call(xAxis);
```

I've attached an image for reference: axis appears right at the top of the SVG element; I expected it to appear at the bottom instead.  [image: axis appears right at the top of the SVG element; I expected it to appear at the bottom instead.]

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation [d3.axisBottom](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axisBottom)

> Constructs a new bottom-oriented axis generator for the given scale, with empty tick arguments, a tick size of 6 and padding of 3. In this orientation, ticks are drawn below the horizontal domain path.

So, you still have to translate the axis.